# Conditionally Mandatory Field in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to make a field conditionally mandatory? If in a dropdown a user selects "Other", the next field should be mandatory, optional otherwise.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do that. You can write a client field change function and do something like this.

```
 var field0=context.currentRecord.getText({fieldId: ‘field0'});
  if(field0 === ‘Other’) {
      context.currentRecord.getField({fieldId: ‘field1'}).isMandatory=true;
  } else {
      context.currentRecord.getField({fieldId:’field1’}).isMandatory=false
  }
```

You could also make it possible via workflow as well. But for small validations and stuff it would be better if script is used rather than a workflow.

Comment: **Note:** Me mentioning script would better than a workflow is completely in a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

For small validations I find it best house a workflow rather than a script  (contrary to the other answer). Most companies have admins and few have developers. Workflows should allow anyone to manage it.

In either case make sure you handle setting it to mandatory AND unsetting it. If a user selects other "accidentally" and then changes their option to something other than "other", the field should most likely no longer be mandatory